# Why does string::c_str() return a const char* when strings are allocated dynamically?

Tags: c++, string, char, constants

Why does it return a **constant char** pointer? The C++11 standard says:

> The pointer returned points to the internal array currently used by the string object to store the characters that conform its value.

How can something that is dynamically allocated be constant(`const char*`)?

Comment: The API to the internal buffer is through a `const char*` interface.  That member function is provided to conveniently interoperate with C APIs that need to access a non-mutable character array as a C-style string.

Comment: Are you asking "how a const pointer can point to non-const things"? Or "why provide a const pointer when a non-const one would be possible"?

Comment: The first one, I had the misconception that a `const T*` has to point to a constant

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C and C++, `const` translates more or less to "read only".

So, when something returns a `char const *`, that doesn't necessarily mean the data it's pointing at is actually `const`--it just means that the pointer you're receiving only supports reading, not writing, the data it points at.

The string object itself may be able to modify that data--but (at least via the pointer you're receiving) you're not allowed to modify the data directly.

Answer (score 1):

The pointer returned by `c_str` is declared to point to a `const char` to prevent modifying the internal `string` buffer via that pointer.

The `string` buffer is indeed dynamically allocated, and the pointer returned by `c_str` is only valid while the string itself does not change. Quoting from [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str):

> The pointer obtained from `c_str()` may be invalidated by:
>
> - Passing a non-const reference to the string to any standard library function, or
> - Calling non-const member functions on the string, excluding operator[], at(), front(), back(), begin(), rbegin(), end() and rend().

Comment: Addendum: I've never seen it in the wild, but `c_str`, quoting cppreference, *Returns a pointer to a null-terminated character array with data **equivalent** to those stored in the string.* The emphasis is mine because that equivalent is important. The storage pointed at by the pointer returned by `c_str`  doesn't have to be the same as `string`'s internal storage, and if they are different, what's the point of modifying it? Crom only knows what you just modified.

Comment: @user4581301 That's interesting wording which I didn't pay attention to, and honestly don't know what deeper meaning it's trying to convey. The [standard](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.string#string.ops) is pretty clear that `c_str` "*returns a pointer `p` such that `p + i == addressof(operator[](i))` for each `i in [0, size()]`*".

Comment: And that wording goes back [at least as far as C++11](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/strings). I know in the old days all sorts of weird could be going on behind the scenes, but unless we're both reading the Standard incorrectly, the quote puts a nail in all of the odd cases I can think of that could provide an alternative buffer , at least for modern C++. Maybe equivalent is still there for the sake of those still building to c++98 or 03.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to interpret the question as why can't you cast it back to a `char *` and write to it and expect it to work.

The standard library reserves the option to itself to lazy-copy strings in the copy constructor; thus if you wrote to it via the result of `c_str()` you would potentially write to other strings. As most uses of `c_str()` would not need to write to the string, dedupling on the call to `c_str()` would impose too large a penalty.